# Where can I read the Bhagavad Gita with the commentary of Vishwanath Chakravarti Thakura in English in a PDF version?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, translation-request, resource

I would like to read the commentary of Vishwanath Chakravarti Thakura of the Bhagavad Gita in English in a PDF version. Can anyone provide me the site where I can download the relevant PDF file?

Comment: I searched but can not found a free pdf only purchasable

Comment: @Fierce lord Its okay. Thanks for trying.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/S%C4%81r%C4%81rtha-Var%E1%B9%A3i%E1%B9%87%C4%AB-%E1%B9%AC%C4%ABk%C4%81-Commentary-Bhagavad-ebook/dp/B0133E1VSO this is available for free  as  kindle unlimited edition. You can ask Keshav as he has Kindle unlimited account IIRC.